# How to update package version and reference renamed dll via nuget?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

### As is

I have my own project on .NET 5 which references the lib A via nuget, the lib A references lib B (version 5.0.1) via nuget.

[image: as is]

The name of lib B's dll for version 5 is `HealthChecks.IdSvr.dll`

### To be

Now I'm trying to update my project to .NET 6. And I should update the version of Lib B to 6.0.1.

[image: to be]

Firstly I have added the reference to lib B `v6.0.1` to my project and it would work, but the developer of Lib B changed the name of dll to `HealthChecks.OpenIdConnectServer.dll`.

And when Lib A tries to reach to Lib B I have an exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'HealthChecks.IdSvr, Version=5.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'HealthChecks.IdSvr, Version=5.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

### Question

Is there a way to say Lib A that the Lib B's dll name have changed to `HealthChecks.OpenIdConnectServer.dll`?

I can not recompile lib A with updated dependency.

Here is the links:

- [Lib A](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.UI/)
- [Lib B](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.OpenIdConnectServer)

---

UPDATE:

Tried to copy dll after build, but no luck, still having exception.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.OpenIdConnectServer" Version="6.0.1">
    <IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>


<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)\HealthChecks.OpenIdConnectServer.dll"
        DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\HealthChecks.IdSvr.dll" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Sounds like Lib A should be updated to accept .net 6 https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin/issues/926

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes you are right. but as you can see it is not upgraded yet :(

Comment: You could potentially rewrite the dll back to its old name with [ildasm/ilasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) but that sounds ridiculously nasty. The only good options are not to upgrade B, or get a version of A built against the new version of B